# Rails and Heroku - some errors in production environment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

ruby: 3.0.3 
rails: 6.0.4 
mysql2: 0.4.4

I am working on creating a web application with booking function like airbnb.
When I try to book a room after deploying on heroku, the booking function does not work well.

What I have noticed was that I encountered following errors.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms | Allocations: 1700)
```

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "2022-04-26"
```

I have been looking into the solutions for these errors but not overcome yet.

What are the causes of this error in this case?

Lastly, I am sorry if my question is not clear.

**Partial heroku logs**

```
2022-04-14T12:58:55.108837+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.108771 #4]  INFO -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] Started POST "/reservations" for 124.154.102.247 at 2022-04-14 12:58:55 +0000
2022-04-14T12:58:55.109680+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.109628 #4]  INFO -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] Processing by ReservationsController#create as HTML
2022-04-14T12:58:55.109710+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.109684 #4]  INFO -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"9iOwT3LEJkWrVJiKrOdHSP15gGi312/aImUpOn1eBf52hGP/k6CTkVEvRSZ07MXIz/RNRwUIt63T7aBMa52WtQ==", "reservation"=>{"start_date"=>"2022-04-24", "end_date"=>"2022-04-26", "room_id"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Book now"}
2022-04-14T12:58:55.113409+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.113356 #4] DEBUG -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.115519+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.115456 #4] DEBUG -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]   Room Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.117064+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.117019 #4] DEBUG -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.119157+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.119105 #4] DEBUG -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]    (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."room_id" = $1 AND (('2022-04-24' <= start_date AND start_date <= '2022-04-26')
2022-04-14T12:58:55.119158+00:00 app[web.1]: OR ('2022-04-24' <= end_date AND end_date <= '2022-04-26')
2022-04-14T12:58:55.119158+00:00 app[web.1]: OR (start_date < '2022-04-24' AND '2022-04-26' < 9))  [["room_id", 6]]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.119373+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.119342 #4]  INFO -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms | Allocations: 1700)
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120538+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/reservations" host=******.herokuapp.com request_id=609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e fwd="124.154.102.247" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120597+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-04-14T12:58:55.120556 #4] FATAL -- : [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120598+00:00 app[web.1]: [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "2022-04-26"
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120599+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 3:       OR (start_date < '2022-04-24' AND '2022-04-26' < 9))
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120599+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120600+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120600+00:00 app[web.1]: [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e]
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120614+00:00 app[web.1]: [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:70:in `has_conflict'
2022-04-14T12:58:55.120614+00:00 app[web.1]: [609a3c32-af08-49a0-b437-41006dd2e93e] app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:38:in `create'
```

**reservation controller**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @reservation = current_user.reservations.new(reservation_params)
    @room = Room.find(params[:reservation][:room_id])
    start_date = Date.parse(params[:reservation][:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(params[:reservation][:end_date])

    if current_user == @room.user
      flash[:alert] = "You cannot book your own room!"
    else
      if has_conflict(start_date, end_date, @room)
        flash[:alert] = "Dates are unavailable"
      else
        nights = (end_date - start_date).to_i
        @reservation.total_nights = nights
        @reservation.total_price = @room.price * nights
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully Reserved Room!"
        @reservation.save
      end
    end
    redirect_to request.referer
  end

  private
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :room_id)
  end

  def has_conflict(start_date, end_date, room)
    check = room.reservations.where(
      "(? <= start_date AND start_date <= ?)
      OR (? <= end_date AND end_date <= ?)
      OR (start_date < ? AND ? < 9)",
      start_date, end_date,
      start_date, end_date,
      start_date, end_date
    )
    check.size > 0 ? true : false
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="container-fluid my-5">
    <div class="row m-5">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <p class="m-0", style="font-size: 1.7rem;">$<%= @room.price %></p>
                        <p class="m-0">Per night</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <%= form_with(model: @reservation, local: true) do |f| %>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
                                <%= f.label :start_date, 'Check in' %>
                                <%= f.text_field :start_date, id:"start_date", class:"w-100 booking-form border border-light rounded p-1", readonly: true, placeholder: "Start date" %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
                                <%= f.label :end_date, 'Check out' %>
                                <%= f.text_field :end_date, id:"end_date", class:"w-100 booking-form border border-light rounded p-1", readonly: true, placeholder: "End date", disable: true %>
                            </div>
                            <%= f.hidden_field :room_id, value: @room.id %>
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: none;" id="preview">
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    Price ($): 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <%= @room.price %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    Total Nights: 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <span id="total-nights"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mt-3">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    Total Price ($): 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <span id="total-price"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center my-4">
                            <%= f.submit 'Book now', id: "submit", class: 'btn btn-warning w-100', disabled: true %>
                        </div>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#start_date").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            $("#end_date").attr("disabled", false);

            var start_date = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
            var end_date = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
            var nights = (end_date - start_date)/1000/60/60/24;

            if (start_date != null && end_date != null) {
                $('#preview').show();
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#total-nights").text(nights);
                var total_price = nights * <%= @room.price %>
                $("#total-price").text(total_price);
            }
        });
        $("#end_date").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
        }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            var start_date = $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate");
            var end_date = $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate");
            var nights = (end_date - start_date)/1000/60/60/24;

            if (start_date != null && end_date != null) {
                $('#preview').show();
                $("#submit").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#total-nights").text(nights);
                var total_price = nights * <%= @room.price %>
                $("#total-price").text(total_price);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: data type of start_date and end_date is following: 't.date :start_date' 't.date :end_date'

Comment: ***OR (start_date < ? AND ? < 9)",*** you are are comparing end_date to 9

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will fix it and see how it goes.